# Frozen Wings or Bone Wings?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I have terraria and I just recently got Frozen Wings. Then, later when I was farming in my dungeon I got a Bone Feather used to craft Bone Wings. so I was wondering, "**Which one is the better wing, Frozen Wings or Bone Wings?**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wings), here are my results:

### Bone Wings [image: Bone Wings' Stats]

### Frozen Wings [image: Frozen Wings' Stats]

### Differences

1. Frozen Wings can be seen in the dark, whereas Bone Wings cannot.
2. The time before the wings stop flapping is different. **Bone Wings: 2.33 seconds, Frozen Wings: 2.67 seconds**
3. The height the wings can fly to is also different. **Bone Wings: 72 blocks, Frozen Wings: 81 blocks**
4. Lastly, the Horizontal Flight Speed Bonus is different as well. **Bone Wings: 133%, Frozen Wings: 150%**

This shows that **Frozen Wings** can fly *higher*, fly *faster*, and *fly longer* than **Bone Wings**,

**Therefore, this indicates that *Frozen Wings* is better than *Bone Wings*.**